# [Doctrine][Symfony] Multiple Joins in a single annotation request (is it possible ?)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I'm working on a Symfony project (V3.4) and I'm using an existing DB (can't change it).
To interact with it I use doctrine annotations and the work is well done!
I manage to submit requests using JoinTable and JoinColumns but there is one last thing I don't know how to deal with ...

I have the following tables :

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPKYr.png)

I have the id from table A and I'm trying to get the libelle from the E table.

Is there a way to do it using annotations? For now I've already done it between 3 tables but I don't know how to do it for more :

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="",joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(
 name="",referencedColumnName="")}, inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(
 name="",referencedColumnName="", unique=true)})
```

If it's not possible I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: this is the official documentation of Doctrine, the ORM that you are ussing, i would help more than this: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your need and your schema, i can tell you that you don't need many to many relationship. You should bidirectional relation across the entities(tables).

I don't know which kind of relation you have right now, but assuming one-to-one, you can setup relations following way:

**EntityA**

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityB", mappedBy="entityA")
 */
private $entityB;
```

**EntityB**

```
 /**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityA", inversedBy="entityB")
 * @JoinColumn(name="entityA_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $entityA;
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityC", mappedBy="entityB")
 */
private $entityC;
```

**EntityC**

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityB", inversedBy="entityC")
 * @JoinColumn(name="entityB_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $entityB;
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityD", mappedBy="entityC")
 */
private $entityD;
```

**EntityD**

```
 /**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityC", inversedBy="entityD")
 * @JoinColumn(name="entityC_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $entityC;
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityE", mappedBy="entityE")
 */
private $entityE;
```

**EntityE**

```
 /**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityD", inversedBy="entityE")
 * @JoinColumn(name="entityD_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $entityD;
```

I didn't have time to test it. But it should be straight forward.

You can get libelle from E table following way:

```
$entityA = $entityRepositoryForA->find(a_id_here);
$entityA->getEntityB()->getEntityC()->getEntityD()->getEntityE->getLibelle();
```

Comment: Note that you should use custom queries to get `E`, using the above method of chaining `->getEntity*()` results in excessive queries (up to 5-6 queries for the 2 lines above).